# SAFEARRAY on linux

Tags: c++, linux, safearray

I'm using a proprietary library on linux that uses `SAFEARRAY` type in a callback function:

`HRESULT Write(SAFEARRAY *Data)`

`SAFEARRAY` is defined in a header file as `typedef void SAFEARRAY`.

I must define a callback function that will get the data (eg. as `*unsigned char`) and it's length (eg. as `int` or `size_t`) and write the data somewhere.

Something like:

```
HRESULT MyWrite(SAFEARRAY *Data) {
  unsigned char *data = SafeArrayGetData(Data);
  size_t length = SafeArrayGetLength(Data);
  write_data_somewhere(data, length);
}
```

And then use it with the library:

```
ProprietaryLib::ExportThing(thing, MyWrite);
```

So my question is: How to get the data and it's length on linux, where I have no [oaidl.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/oaidl/) or [oleauto.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/oleauto/) header file.

Comment: `SAFEARRAY Data` I'm pretty sure that a named argument may not be void.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the *

Comment: C++ arrays don't store the length anywhere. There's no way to get the length of an arbitrary array.

Comment: Does the library provide a way to get the length of the array?

Comment: I cannot get the length of the data with the library. SAFEARRAY is a Microsoft thing and they didn't provide a way to use it in the linux port of the library.

Comment: `typedef struct tagSAFEARRAY {
  USHORT         cDims;
  USHORT         fFeatures;
  ULONG          cbElements;
  ULONG          cLocks;
  PVOID          pvData;
  SAFEARRAYBOUND rgsabound[1];
} SAFEARRAY;` well, `Data->cbElements` is the size of an array in elements. You should rewrite the headers from scratch from the documentation.

Comment: Library should provide you functions to extract needed data from SAFEARRAY or header with definition of structure. Do they provide example code? SAFEARRAY is ugly beast https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt778923.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @Frane thanks, that link is great. So I try to implement my own `MYSAFEARRAY` from that definition, then cast the `Data` pointer to `MYSAFEARRAY` and see what's in it.

Comment: @KamilCuk when I cast the `Data` pointer to `MYSAFEARRAY` (which is a struct defined as that in your comment), the structure is weird. `cDims` is big (like `60128`).`cbElements` is 0, and `pvData` points to memory that is not owned by the process and fails with segmentation fault if I try to touch it. Any advice?

Comment: On MS Windows you need to lock SAFEARRAY before accessing data.
That library doesn't seem well ported to linux.
Is there any other way to retrieve data besides `ProprietaryLib::ExportThing`?

Comment: There is just `ProprietaryLib::ExportToFile(thing, filename)` but I wanted to avoid writing and then reading a file.

Comment: If you can, try to redefine it in terms of `std::vector`. If you can't, I'll shed a tear for you.

Comment: @Clearer just cast it to `std::vector`?

Comment: What's the name of this proprietary linux library? Does it support locking/unlocking of the SAFEARRAY? Seems like an odd beast to use in linux.

Comment: It is the ABBYY FineReader SDK, and to me it appears that it was first written for windows and then somehow automatically ported to linux. These MS types are defined in an header (like the `HRESULT`, `USHORT`, ...) and also `SAFEARRAY` is there as `void` (but an comment above the `SAFEARRAY` definition says `//not supported`). It is a mystery to me, how can they compile  on linux the shared lib with `SAFEARRAY` in it, but no definition/implementation of the type exists.

Comment: What does the FineReader's SDK documentation say about these callbacks? Have you confirmed that you actually get the calls to the callback function? Perhaps asking (or searching) in [Knowledge Base - ABBYY FineReader Engine 11 for Linux](https://knowledgebase.abbyy.com/?&ProductId=375&version=fbb2edb1-b5a2-4b20-a593-031bf8e8227e&platform=7dc0873a-de9d-4f99-8b6e-7d0e8bc98f10) will be more fruitful.

Comment: There is nothing in the knowledge base about the interface i'm implementing. And the documentation doesn't talk about what to do with `IFileWriter::Write` and the `SAFEARRAY` argument in linux. It's takes it as if it where the same on all platforms.

Comment: Ok, but if you ask a question about how to implement the interface in Linux in that forum, chances are probably greater that you find someone that has first hand experience doing just that.

Comment: My question is there for 6 days without an answer https://forum.ocrsdk.com/thread/how-to-get-data-from-safearray/

Comment: I see. I would try contacting ABBYY directly in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts on the matter:

- Maybe you've seen it already, but Wine implements `SAFEARRAY`. Thus you may have a look at

  - https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/master/dlls/oleaut32/safearray.c
  - https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/master/include/oaidl.idl
  - https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/master/include/oleauto.h
- It seems to me that to get length and data of the array, it should be fine to just access the members of the struct. For instance, in `safearray.c` they simply read `cbElements` at various places, and the method `SafeArrayAccessData` basically only returns `pvData`. (In addition, it "locks" the array. The "locking" seems to be a reference counter that is checked when a SAFEARRAY is resized or freed.)

  One idea why your `MYSAFEARRAY` (mentioned in comments) does not work is 
  that struct packing might interfere. In https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zp-struct-member-alignment they say that Windows SDK presupposes that structs are packed on 8-byte boundaries. So perhaps you could output the raw bytes and see if you detect a pattern. If that turns out to be the problem, try to change your compiler settings.

Comment: I've seen the Wine `SAFEARRAY` implementation, but without the correct structure it will not work. `pvData` points to not allocated memory and `cbElements` is always 0.  Also tried to write the bytes to binary file and then inspect it with a hex editor, but there is hard to find a pattern. Now i'm experimenting with gcc's `-fpack-struct=8` and `__attribute__((aligned(8))` with no success. Also it is interesting that the fist bytes are an pointer to somewhere. When I do `struct S { void *p} *x =(struct S)Data`, I can read the value in `*x->p`.